# Prestashop - .htaccess URL Rewriting (add perso link)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, prestashop

I want to know why the personal links (for url Rewriting) are not working with Prestashop...

I Did a test with (add in the end of the file):

```
RewriteRule ^test$ /index.php [L]
```

But it doesn't work. I searched on the web but I don't find something...
The default URL rewriting by Prestashop works but I can't add other links

Can you help me ? Do you need more information ?

Thanks

The htaccess file :

```
# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Images
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com$
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com$
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

FileETag INode MTime Size
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404

# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again

## Ajout manuelle ##
# RewriteRule ^kit-chaine-afam.htm$ /content/6-kit-chaine-afam [L]
RewriteRule ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com/kit-chaine-afam.htm$ /index.php?id_cms=6&controller=cms [L]
RewriteRule ^/test$ /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com/test2$ www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com$
RewriteRule ^test3$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [L]
```

Comment: any solution? share it if you have one

Answer (score 0):

These two

```
RewriteRule ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com/kit-chaine-afam.htm$ /index.php?id_cms=6&controller=cms [L]
RewriteRule ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com/test2$ www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com/index.php [L]
```

cannot work, because the domain is not part of the URL-path pattern.

This rule *should* work

```
RewriteRule ^/test$ /index.php [L]
```

but this rule above from Prestashop

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

prevents it.

You can move your rule above the Prestashop definitions

```
RewriteRule ^test$ /index.php [L]

# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com$
...
```

and then, the `/test` rule will work as expected. But be careful to not interfere with Prentashop's rules.

Comment: Nop, I did other test but still not work. I updated my post with the full code Htacess

Comment: Thanks for the explains but still not work as you can see : http://www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com/test  // Should I delete "RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]" ?

Comment: @Snow This might have to do with leading or trailing slashes, I changed the pattern to `^/?test/?$`. Please see updated answer.

Comment: @Snow It seems, I had some redirect caching issues in my browser. I updated my answer.

Comment: I did it but it doesn't work... maybe I can't add new rules with Prestashop ? It strange, if you need more informations, ask me.

Comment: @Snow Then I'm out of ideas. Moving the rule before the other rules works in my simplified test environment.

Comment: I think that with Prestashop there is a system of "dispatcher" who can be priority... compared with the htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a simple "RedirectPermanent" in your htacces file ?

```
    RedirectPermanent /old_page_urlp /new_page_url
```

is it working ?

Comment: I tried with : RedirectPermanent www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com/test89   www.accessoires-de-la-moto.com/index.php  but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You just go Preferences->SEO & URLs. In the Setup URLs section, switch Friendly URLs to yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the URL rewriting configurations and rules from the admin panel:

> Preferences -> SEO & URLs ->  SCHEMA OF URLS

[image]